# Regression for poisson process in R

Tags: r, regression, software, poisson-process

I have a series of samples of varying length, and the number of bugs created in those time samples. Reading the literature, this is often modeled as a Poisson process. If you write it like:

$$P(k,t)=\frac{e^{-\lambda t}(\lambda t)^k}{k!}$$

I know $k$ and $t$ and would like to regress to find $\lambda$.

Is there an R package to do this? The standard `glm` works for Poisson regression, but I can't find anything which allows for samples having non-unit times.

Comment: Since $\lambda t=E[X]$, I could do regression on that instead, but I'm not sure if that's valid. It's seems like the error in OLS to find $\lambda t = X$ would be different than in an actual Poisson regression.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can still use `glm` in R, but you include the log of $t$ as an 'offset' to take it into account, something like:

```
fit <- glm( k ~ 1 + offset(log(t)), data=mydata, family=poisson)
```

This will fit an intercept that will be the estimate of $\lambda$, but you could also include covariates if needed.

Comment: Cool! But why do I have to take the log? I guess I might not understand the offset function - I thought it just forced the coefficient to be 1.

Comment: The natural link for Poisson regression is the log (and offset is addative).  You want $E(x) = log(\lambda t) = log(\lambda) + log(t)$  The intercept will then be the log of lambda since you set the offset (with coefficient 1 as you say) set as log(t).

Comment: To build on the last comment, exp(log(lambda) + log(t)) equals t * lambda.  In other words, adding log(t) increases the expected number of events by a factor of t.  So sampling for twice as long should net you twice as many events.